# Digital Signature in PDF doesn't verify as matching after adding annotations

Tags: pdf, adobe, digital-signature, digest

I was going through the official [PDF spec](https://wwwimages2.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference_archive/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf). I came across a digitally signed PDF [here](https://blogs.adobe.com/security/SampleSignedPDFDocument.pdf). While I was analyzing its catalog dictionary, I saw this:

[image]

The digital signature is in the form of a signature field, which specifies the byte range of the content to which the signature applies. Any content added on top of it, like annotation, notes, etc. should go in as incremental updates, so the validity of the original content should continue to hold true (excluding direct editing of the content, like changing the **Sample** word to **Sample2**). However, when I open the file in Nitro, add some highlight or notes to it, save it and open it in Acrobat, it now says that the signature is invalid. Which brings me to my questions:

1. Why is Acrobat showing it as invalid? The signature field does not enforce prevention from adding incremental updates, why exactly is it invalid?
2. Why is Acrobat not allowing addition of notes or highlights? Nitro allows it, for example. There is no **Perms** dictionary which would specify a **DocMDP** level restriction, so what exactly it is that Adobe is interpreting as a document level lock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already explained in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49464065/1729265) to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49437574/1729265) on this topic, the file you call *"the official [PDF spec](https://wwwimages2.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference_archive/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf)"* is everything but. The official PDF specification is ISO 32000-1 (since 2008) and ISO 32000-2 (the 2017 update).

That answer also points out the origin of the **P** entry in the **FieldMDP** transform dictionary your sreenshot shows:

It comes from the **Lock** dictionary of the same signature dictionary and is defined in [Adobe supplement to ISO 32000, extension level 3](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/adobe_supplement_iso32000.pdf), (which being from Adobe unfortunately indeed references the PDF Reference 1.7 instead of ISO 32000-1):

> **P** number *(Optional; Extension Level 3) The access permissions granted for this document. Valid values follow:
>
> 1, no changes to the document are permitted; any change to the document invalidates the signature.

This extension to ISO 32000-1 has been added to the standard ISO 32000-2.

Thus,

> 1. Why is Acrobat showing it as invalid? The signature field does not enforce prevention from adding incremental updates, why exactly is it invalid?

Because it **does** enforce prevention of any change, see above.

> 2. Why is Acrobat not allowing addition of notes or highlights? Nitro allows it, for example. There is no Perms dictionary which would specify a DocMDP level restriction, so what exactly it is that Adobe is interpreting as a document level lock?

Because Nitro (at least the version you tested) does probably merely support ISO 32000-1 but not Adobe's extension 3 to it let alone ISO 32000-2.

Comment: Aha. Got it. The `P` entry is missing in the old spec. The new spec starts with this line: **Add the new P entry to Table 8.82 on page 697 of the PDF Reference**. But now that it allows both `Action` and `P` keys to denote the fillability of forms, what if the `Action` keys has a value `All`, meaning all form fields are to be locked, whereas `P` contains 2, meaning form fields are allowed to be modified?

Comment: A **P** value of 2 merely allows editing form fields which are not otherwise protected (be it by means of field flags or by a **Lock** with an **Action** value including it).

Comment: Thanks. Just to make sure that I understand, based on the new spec which you linked, if the first cut of the PDF had a **P** value of 2 (thus allowing signing), and a subsequent change adds a field with a **P** value of 3, because 3 is less restrictive than 2, it will be ignored, and all further changes will have to abide by the rules of **2** unless somebody sets **P** to 1. Is that right? However, what happens when a subsequent fields sets **P** to 1? Then is it that all future updates will have to abide by **1**, and all past updates have to abide by **2**?

Comment: Correct. Restrictions only get stricter. And the new value counts starting after the revision in which the signature field in question was signed. Thus, after the signature field with **P** = 1 is signed, no changes are allowed anymore. Except, that is, if you support ISO 32000-2 or the ETSI extensions to ISO 32000-1, then additions of validation related information and document time stamps are allowed.

Comment: Thanks MKL! As usual, authoritative answer! An unrelated query, can you recommend any software which allows user to add PKCS SHA1 or x509.rsa.sha1 signing, or allows various facets of FieldMDP or DocMDP to be enforced, like specifying certain form fields to be locked? Acrobat seems to allow only PKCS7 detached signature, at least Acrobat DC, and not allowing form fields to be specified.

Comment: @SexyBeast *"can you recommend any software which allows user to add PKCS SHA1 or x509.rsa.sha1 signing"* - Nothing current. **adbe.x509.rsa_sha1** and **adbe.pkcs7.sha1** are deprecated in PDF 2.0. **adbe.pkcs7.sha1** type signature even require the use of SHA1. I cannot recommend the use of any current program actively supporting the creation of deprecated or even clearly insecure signatures. If old programs are ok, I'd propose using an appropriately old Adobe Acrobat version (I'd guess around version 6) with the required additional signature handlers installed.

Comment: @SexyBeast *"... allows various facets of FieldMDP or DocMDP to be enforced, like specifying certain form fields to be locked? Acrobat seems to [...] not allow form fields to be specified."*. Acrobat 9.5 still allowed specifying fields, cf. [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3UBf.png);  I'd actually be surprised if Acrobat DC does not; unfortunately I cannot test, though, as I don't have a current Acrobat version.

Comment: Thanks **mkl**! I do have Acrobat 9.5, however I am unable to find the alert whose picture your posted. Can you give the steps through which I can reach that alert? I am trying out with a PDF that does have form fields.

Comment: @SexyBeast Open the file in Adobe Acrobat - Select menu item Forms, "Add or Edit Fields..." - Select your signature field and click right for context menu - select "Properties" - Select tab "Signed"

Comment: Thanks mkl. I tried that, I don't get the menu as you said: https://imgur.com/a/RMBSTRV

Comment: @SexyBeast probably you have to use "edit form in designer..."

Comment: No, finally got it! This link - https://wwwimages2.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/security/acrobat_digsig_userguide_90.pdf page 63 helped me!